# What are the disadvantages of using template_redirect for restrictions

Tags: plugins, templates

We can use template_redirect action to check if the user has authorized to view a specific post or page and redirect to different page. What's the disadvantages or issues of using template_redirect action in this case as its not intended for that feature

Thanks

Comment: Nothing I can think of. It's intended for redirects, and you're using it for redirects. What makes you think there'd be an issue?

Comment: I'll second @JacobPeattie - nothing wrong with using `template_redirect`, at this point the query has been issued and globals populated, so you can inspect `$wp_query` and `$wp` and use template conditional tags fine. If you want to make a determination before the query has been issued, you can hook into `do_parse_request` or a little later in the same process `request` and or `parse_request` respectively, which fire sequentially in that order just before the main the query.

Comment: I think i should have specially mentioned about archive pages. In archive pages, i have to check restrictions for each post inside the page. So the redirection is not possible. Thats the main issue I am having now